# how do i pick more than one winner?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So what im doing here is picking a winner out of the people i have mentioned **for example: +giveaway 1 @user1 @user2 @user3** and it randomly picks out a winner for me. What i wanna do is pick more than one winner. I am kinda new to javascript so help would be much appreciated.

```
const discord = require('discord.js')

module.exports = {
  commands: ['giveaway', 'pick'],
  minArgs: 2,
  expectedArgs: "<Winner Amount> <Targets>",
  permissionError: 'You must have the right permissions to use this command.',
  // permissions: 'ADMINISTRATOR',
  callback: async (message, arguments) => {
    const mentions = message.mentions.users
    const members = mentions.map(user => user.username)
    const ranMembers = shuffle(members)

    const embed1 = new discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('RED')
    .setDescription('Please tag the users to pick from!')
    const embed2 = new discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('RED')
    .setDescription('Please provide the amount of winners!')

    if (mentions.size === 0) {
      message.channel.send(embed1)
      return
    }

    const winners = arguments[0]
    if (isNaN(winners)) {
      message.channel.send(embed2)
      return
    }

    if (winners == 1) {
        const embed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('RANDOM')
        .setTitle(' Giveaway Winner')
        .setDescription(`**${ranMembers.random()}** has won the giveaway!`)
        message.channel.send(embed)
        return
    } else if (winners == 2) {
        
    }
  }
}

function shuffle(array) {
    var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;  
    while (0 !== currentIndex) {
  
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;
  
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }
    return array;
}

Array.prototype.random = function () {
    return this[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.length)];
};
```

Comment: Two winners is a quarrel, more than two is a war ... Could you please explain your issue with the code with more details?

Comment: @Teemu despite that, the OP should probably look into `Array.prototype.slice` for a solution

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can shuffle your array multiple times and select the N first elements

```
let members = mentions.map(user => user.username)

//Shuffle array 10 times
for(i=0; i<10; i++){ members = shuffle(members)}

//Then choose the first N (Number of winners)
const selectedWinners = members.slice(0, winners);
```

Then you can change your message to...

```
.setDescription(`**${winners.join(",")}** won the giveaway!`)
```